# Jquery UI click not working on dragged images. When the images > 1

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, user-interface, jquery-ui

there the code is working yet the problem is that when I add an image. I can click it. But when I add the next one I can click only the new one. If I want to click another I need to drag it. And then I can click only the one I dragged.

It is not < canvas > just div called canvas.

What I did wrong?

```
function newImage(image){
var img = new Image()
var imgWidth = 0
var imgHeight = 0
img.onload = function (){
    imgWidth = img.naturalWidth
    console.log(img.naturalWidth)
    imgHeight = img.naturalHeight
    console.log(img.naturalHeight)
}
img.src = image.url
    $('#canvas').append('' +

            '<div id="img-'+image.id+'" class="position-absolute selectable position-relative" style="top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 0px; height: 0px; outline-offset: -2px;">' +
                '<img class="" id="realImg-'+image.id+'" src="'+image.url+'" style="left: 0px; top: 0px; width: 100%; height: 100%; mix-blend-mode: unset;">' +// to ma .nameide i .speed
            '</div>'
    )
    setInterval(function(){
        $('#img-'+image.id).css('width', imgWidth)
        $('#realImg-'+image.id).css('width', imgWidth)
        $('#img-'+image.id).css('height', imgHeight)
        $('#realImg-'+image.id).css('height', imgHeight)
    }, 100)
        $('#img-'+image.id).draggable({
            start: function( event, ui ) {
                $('.selectable').css('outline', '0px solid gold')
                console.log('reselect')
                activeImg = "#realImg-"+image.id
                activeImgId = image.id
                //$('#img-'+activeImgId).css('outline', '2px dashed white')
                $('#img-'+activeImgId).addClass('border-blend')
                console.log('selected')
            }
        }).on('mouseup', function (){
            if ( $(this).is('.ui-draggable-dragging') ) {
                return;
            }
            
                    activeImg = "#realImg-"+image.id
                    //$('#img-'+activeImgId).css('outline', '2px dashed white')
                    $('#img-'+activeImgId).addClass('border-blend')
                    //$('#realImg-'+image.id).css('marginLeft', '-2px')
                    //$('#realImg-'+image.id).css('marginTop', '-2px')
                    console.log('selected')

        })
}
```

Here you can see a live example: https://jsfiddle.net/Lyd291jr/1/

And by the way, it is unselecting after stop dragging. This is also a problem.

Comment: Please create a [mcve]

Comment: i have done it. try it

Comment: Please move all inline styles to CSS classes. Also cache references to things like `$('#img-'+image.id)`  and remove commented code, when you do such things the code will become much more cleaner and easier to read and understand. The solution to stacking is a CSS fix, but it's very hard for other people to understand all your styles written as inline styles

Answer (score 0):

You can apply `display: flex` to `#canvas`:

```
#canvas{
  display: flex;
}
```

And remove the hardcoded inline absolute positioning, `height:0;` etc like this: https://jsfiddle.net/r0q1agwb/